# What happens when creating contract but out of gas?

Tags: contract-deployment, gas, gas-refund

I am new to ethereum.

I have learned that all states will be rolled back if out of gas.

Assuming that there is a transaction with value field, but it runs out of gas. Will the value be back? (i know the gas will never be back)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the value sent will be refunded / not deducted from your account. The account balance is also part of the "state". An errored transaction will revert all the changes it makes or you can say an errored transaction makes no changes to the chain state (except for the tx fees burnt and paid to the miners).